# .NET / C# HttpClient - Usage in Mono

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, mono, httpclient

I'm currently doing a project which heavily uses the .NET / C# HttpClient.

Since the project is UI based (GTK#), my requests need to be asynchronous for being able to update a progress bar.
I send just below 1000 requests, collect the results, serialize them and save them to file as XML.

This works pretty well in Windows, however when running my application in Linux using Mono, the requests seem to be executed much slower.
While it takes somewhat below 10 Minutes to get all requests in Windows, Mono takes something like half an hour for it.
What I'm doing is using the HttpClient.GetStringAsync and HttpClient.GetAsync methods, while awaiting them with .ConfigureAwait(false) for ensuring that they don't block my UI thread.
I reuse the HttpClient all the time, so I create it once and use it for all requests (which is the recommended way).

A minimal example of how I send the requests would look as follows:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private async static Task<string> GetContent(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    return await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.de").ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async static void RetrieveData(){
    using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var responseContents = new List<string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
        {
            var pageContent = await GetContent(httpClient).ConfigureAwait(false);
            responses.Add(pageContent);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am wondering about right now: Is there anything special about the Mono implementation of the HttpClient, so that I would have to set some special settings for it to work as fast as on Windows?

I already recognized, that the XmlReader and XmlWriter want a little more AttributeTags for serializing and deserializing classes, so it might be that the Mono HttpClient has some special traits to it aswell.

Do you know anything about that, or can simply give me a hint, whether the Mono implementation of the HttpClient just is so slow and there is no way for me to change it?

I appreciate any help.

Kind Regards,

Florian

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Without any notion of your code, it is hard to suggest anything at all.

Comment: @Elijan9: Done, thanks.

Comment: Are there any differences in where the code is running that could be affecting it besides being on Linux? E.g. is Linux on a VM and the Windows on tin? What're the differences in the networks if any? There maybe differences in the HttpClient implementations but it sounds a bit red-herring-like unless you've debugged it and gotten to that as a specific cause?

Comment: I've also experienced this. On a server that should be significantly faster running linux / mono, it's much slower than a windows machine on a much slower connection. Webclient is just as slow.